# Web scraping Steam Review with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, steam, review

I have trouble to do what I want which is : Getting all the datas from Steam reviews. I am currently in video-game pre-production and I would like to do some text mining of users reviews of the games that stand near to us in term of gameplay.

I am using Rvest to do so.

2 Questions :
-I can't manage to find a way to separate the review from the posted date. I would like to have them in seperated colums. How could I do that ?
-It works well but... I only have 10 reviews in my data.frame, how do I get them all ? (I spent hours to try to understand how I do that but it seems not possible, because, if I did understand correctly, steam is using a javascript injectiion each time we go to the bottom of the website which rvest doesn't do when it reads the link.

Here is my code :

```
#install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)

link <- "https://steamcommunity.com/app/215080/reviews/"

review <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes("div.apphub_CardTextContent") %>%
  html_text()

opinion <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes("div.title") %>%
  html_text()

hoursplayed <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes("div.hours") %>%
  html_text()

helpful <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes("div.found_helpful") %>%
  html_text()

date <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes("div.date_posted") %>%
  html_text()

tab <- data.frame("Posted" = date, "Review" = review, "Opinion" = opinion, "Hours Played" = hoursplayed, "Number of helpful vote" = helpful)
```

Thank you by advance for your help.

Comment: Is there only 10 reviews on the url you posted? Probably would help if you sent the html of the date you are trying to scrape. I've done this with python and BeautifulSoup, never with R.

Comment: Looks like Steam allows API access to reviews: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews Using that will probably be much easier than scraping, especially if there is weird javascript stuff going on.

Comment: I don't understand how to work with Steam API in R. Could you detail me how it works or maybe giving me a tutorial please ?

Comment: Try reading the API documentation then posting when stuck. You may find it has examples for working with R. You may also find there isn't a service meeting your needs/resources.

Comment: The `httr` [getting started vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html) is a good place to start. [This tutorial](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-access-any-restful-api-using-r-language/how-to/2017/07/21) looks pretty good too

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions with the stringr R package :

```
library(stringr)
library(rvest)

link <- "https://steamcommunity.com/app/215080/reviews/"

review <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes("div.apphub_CardTextContent") %>%
  html_text()

opinion <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes("div.title") %>%
  html_text()

hoursplayed <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes("div.hours") %>%
  html_text()

helpful <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes("div.found_helpful") %>%
  html_text()

date <- read_html(link) %>%
  html_nodes("div.date_posted") %>%
  html_text()

tab <- data.frame("Posted" = date, "Review" = review, "Opinion" = opinion, "Hours Played" = hoursplayed, "Number of helpful vote" = helpful)

date <- str_extract_all(tab$Review, pattern = "Posted.[:space:]\\d{1}[:space:]December")
tab$Review <- str_remove_all(tab$Review, pattern = "Posted.[:space:]\\d{1}[:space:]December")
tab[["date"]] <- date
```